# docker-compose invalid type, it should be a string

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following environment variable configured in a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    ports:
     - 13045:3000
    environment:
     - NODE_CONFIG: '{"DATABASE_URL":"http://db:5984"}'
```

When trying to run `docker-compose up`, I'm getting this error:

```
services.server.environment contains {"NODE_CONFIG": "{\"DATABASE_URL\":\"http://db:5984\"}"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

I need the environment variable to be set to a JSON string (see https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Environment-Variables#node_config)

Am I doing something wrong here? Can I get this to work somehow?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the colon in middle, according to [this comment on github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2854#issuecomment-181767504) using a dict instead of list should work (removing the leading `-` before NODE_CONFIG

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184525/docker-compose-throws-invalid-type-error

Answer (score 17):

The [Docker Compose file reference states](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment), that environment variables are defined as `VARIABLE=value` array elements. For your case, the docker-compose.yml file would need to be changed to this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    ports:
     - 13045:3000
    environment:
     - NODE_CONFIG='{"DATABASE_URL":"http://db:5984"}'
```

Comment: Nope. I tried that first, it doesn't work.

Comment: @TriNguyen Strange, this works for me

Comment: Well, the build would go through, but the node process doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 15):

You need to remove dash in front of variable. Use syntax like that:

```
   environment:
     NODE_CONFIG: '{"DATABASE_URL":"http://db:5984"}'
```

Answer (score 8):

The args elements themselves need to be a string

```
  args:
    - 'MAVEN_USER=$MAVEN_USER'
    - 'MAVEN_PASSWORD=$MAVEN_PASSWORD'
```

Comment: yes, this worked for me today.

Answer (score 2):

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    ports:
     - 13045:3000
    environment:
     NODE_CONFIG: '{"DATABASE_URL":"http://db:5984"}'
```

Just take the dash before NODE_CONFIG out. For some weird reason this dash looks to not be accepted under environment.

The following example is from official postgres docker hub
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

**QQ edit:**

Basically, dashes are lists and no dashes are mappings, so that is why environment variable must not have dashes

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64275361/docker-compose-yml-dash-syntax-in-yaml
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use = sign instead of :

example:

```
     - NODE_CONFIG= '{"DATABASE_URL":"http://db:5984"}'
```